# c# idiom to check / assign variable

Tags: c#, variables, default-value, datarow, validation

I'm writing a lot of code that looks similar to this:

```
DataRow row = <some row queried from database table>
string strVariableName = (row["VariableName"] == )  ?   "" : row["VariableName"].ToString();
```

What I would like to write is something like this:

```
string strVariableName = STRCHK(row["VariableName"])
```

or even better,

```
DEFSTRVAR(VariableName, row, "default string")
```

Is there a way to do such a thing in C# ... or I guess the better question is, "Is there a standard idiom that fills the purpose?"  (That purpose being to insure I have non-null values to work with.)

Comment: I don't quite understand your point but would the operator ?? work?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you're looking for the [null-coalescing operator](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/ms173224.aspx). E.g.:

```
string strVariableName = (row["VariableName"] ?? "default value").ToString();
```

Answer (score 4):

You can use [`??`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/ms173224.aspx) operator

```
string strVariableName = (row["VariableName"] ?? "").ToString();
```

if you want your function write this:

```
string DEFSTRVAR(string name, DataRow row, string default) // put real type of row !
{
     return (row[name]??default).ToString();
}
```

Comment: You forgot to use the `default` parameter.

Answer (score 3):

try this :

```
string strVariableName = (row["VariableName"] ?? string.Empty).ToString();
```

Comment: string strVariableName = row["VariableName"].ToString() ?? string.Empty;

Comment: @elbillaf - that's going to do a ToString() on a null object.  The other answers have got it right.

Comment: if `row["VariableName"]` is null, ToString() will throw an exception, no?